# How to create a list of N items with a budget constraint and multiple conditions on Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, iterator

I have the following df of Premier League players (ROI_top_players):

```
    player                 team         position    cost_2223   total_points  ROI   
0   Mohamed Salah          Liverpool    FWD         13.0        259           29.77 
1   Trent Alexander        Liverpool    DEF         8.4         206           24.52 
2   Jarrod Bowen           West Ham     MID         8.5         204           23.56
3   Kevin De Bruyne        Man  City    MID         12.0        190           15.70
4   Virgil van Dijk        Liverpool    DEF         6.5         183           14.91 
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
151 Jamaal Lascelles       Newcastle    DEF         4.5         45            10.22
152 Ben Godfrey            Everton      GKP         4.5         45            9.57  
153 Aaron Wan-Bissaka      Man Utd      DEF         4.5         41            8.03
154 Brandon Williams       Norwich      DEF         4.0         36            7.23
```

I want to create a list of 15 players (must be 15 - not more, not less), with the highest ROI possible, and it has to fulfill certain conditions:

- **Position constraints**: it must have 2 GKP, 5 DEF, 5 MID, and 3 FWD
- **Budget constraint**: I have a budget of $100, so for each player I add to the list, I must subtract the player's cost (cost_2223) from the budget.
- **Team constraint**: It can't have more than 3 players per club.

Here's my current code:

```
def get_ideal_team_ROI(budget = 100, star_player_limit = 3, gk = 2, df = 5, md = 5, fwd = 3):
    money_team = []
    budget = budget
    positions = {'GK': gk, 'DEF': df, 'MID': md, 'FWD': fwd}
    for index, row in ROI_top_players.iterrows():
       if (budget >= row['cost_2223'] and positions[row['position']] > 0):
           money_team.append(row['player'])
           budget -= row['cost_2223']
           positions[row['position']] = positions[row['position']] - 1
    return money_team
```

This code has two problems:

1. It creates the list BUT, the list does not end up with 15 players.
2. It doesn't fulfill the team constraint (I have more than 3 players per team).

How should I tackle this? I want my code to make sure that I always have enough budget to buy 15 players and that I always have at maximum 3 players per team.

**I do not need all possible combinations. Just ONE team with the highest possible ROI.

Comment: Do you have a way you could share the complete DataFrame?

Comment: Curious, is this for coursework? Given 155 players and breakdown by 4 positions, the _sheer_ number of combinations is extraordinarily high before applying the last two constraints which are more filters, requiring teams to be assembled first. Or start with every 15 combinations out of 155 then whittle down by cost, teams, and positions but that starts off at 2.7 X 10^20 iterations!

Comment: Thinking more, with linear programming problems, usually corner solutions are most optimal. Start with highest ROI players in each position than adjust lowest ROI to meet cost and team constraints.

Comment: This is the [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) with additional constraints. It's not trivial.

Comment: @BeRT2me it's too big to share it here. Why do you ask?

Comment: @Parfait Not for coursework. I don't need all of the possible combinations, just the team with the highest possible ROI.

Comment: @Corralien any ideas of how to tackle it?

Answer (score 1):

As OP did not provide the data, I went and scraped the first 'Fantasy Football players list' I could find. There is no ROI in that data, however there are 'Points', which we will try to maximize, so I guess OP can apply this to maximize the ROI in his data.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t
import pandas as pd
from pulp import *

## get some data approximating OP's data
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

big_df = pd.DataFrame()

url = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/player-list/'
browser.get(url)
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accept All Cookies']"))).click()
    print('cookies accepted')
except Exception as e:
    print('no cookies for you!')
tables_divs = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table/parent::div/parent::div")))
for t in tables_divs:
    category = t.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'h3')
    print(category.text)
    WebDriverWait(t, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table")))
    dfs = pd.read_html(t.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
    for df in dfs:
        df['Type'] = category.text
        big_df = pd.concat([big_df, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
big_df.to_json('f_footie.json')
browser.quit()
footie_df = pd.read_json('f_footie.json')
footie_df.columns = ['Player', 'Team', 'Points', 'Cost', 'Position']
footie_df['Player'] = footie_df.apply( lambda row: row.Player.replace(' ', '_').strip(), axis=1)
footie_df['Cost'] = footie_df.apply( lambda row: row.Cost.split('£')[1], axis=1)
footie_df['Cost'] = footie_df['Cost'].astype('float')
footie_df['Points'] = footie_df['Points'].astype('int')
print(footie_df)
## constraining variables
positions = footie_df.Position.unique()
clubs = footie_df.Team.unique()
budget = 100
available_roles = {
    'Goalkeepers': 2,
    'Defenders': 5,
    'Midfielders': 5,
    'Forwards': 3    
}

names = [footie_df.Player[i] for i in footie_df.index]
teams = [footie_df.Team[i] for i in footie_df.index]
roles = [footie_df.Position[i] for i in footie_df.index]
costs = [footie_df.Cost[i] for i in footie_df.index]
points = [footie_df.Points[i] for i in footie_df.index]
players = [LpVariable("player_" + str(i), cat="Binary") for i in footie_df.index]
prob = LpProblem("Secret Fantasy Player Choices", LpMaximize)
## define the objective -> maximize the points
prob += lpSum(players[i] * points[i] for i in range(len(footie_df)))
## define budget constraint
prob += lpSum(players[i] * footie_df.Cost[footie_df.index[i]] for i in range(len(footie_df))) <= budget

for pos in positions:
  prob += lpSum(players[i] for i in range(len(footie_df)) if roles[i] == pos) <= available_roles[pos]
## add max 3 per team constraint
for club in clubs:
  prob += lpSum(players[i] for i in range(len(footie_df)) if teams[i] == club) <= 3
prob.solve()
df_list = []
for variable in prob.variables():
  if variable.varValue != 0:
    name = footie_df.Player[int(variable.name.split("_")[1])]
    club = footie_df.Team[int(variable.name.split("_")[1])]
    role = footie_df.Position[int(variable.name.split("_")[1])]
    points = footie_df.Points[int(variable.name.split("_")[1])]
    cost = footie_df.Cost[int(variable.name.split("_")[1])]
    df_list.append((name, club, role, points, cost))
    

#     print(name, club, position, points, cost)
result_df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns = ['Name', 'Club', 'Role', 'Points', 'Cost'])
result_df.to_csv('win_at_fantasy_football.csv')
print(result_df)
```

This will display some control printouts, the data scraped, the long printout from pulp solver, and the result dataframe in the end, looking like this:

|  | Name | Club | Role | Points | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Alisson | Liverpool | Goalkeepers | 176 | 5.5 |
| 1 | Lloris | Spurs | Goalkeepers | 158 | 5.5 |
| 2 | Bowen | West Ham | Midfielders | 206 | 8.5 |
| 3 | Saka | Arsenal | Midfielders | 179 | 8 |
| 4 | Maddison | Leicester | Midfielders | 181 | 8 |
| 5 | Ward-Prowse | Southampton | Midfielders | 159 | 6.5 |
| 6 | Gallagher | Chelsea | Midfielders | 140 | 6 |
| 7 | Antonio | West Ham | Forwards | 140 | 7.5 |
| 8 | Toney | Brentford | Forwards | 139 | 7 |
| 9 | Mbeumo | Brentford | Forwards | 119 | 6 |
| 10 | Alexander-Arnold | Liverpool | Defenders | 208 | 7.5 |
| 11 | Robertson | Liverpool | Defenders | 186 | 7 |
| 12 | Cancelo | Man City | Defenders | 201 | 7 |
| 13 | Gabriel | Arsenal | Defenders | 146 | 5 |
| 14 | Cash | Aston Villa | Defenders | 147 | 5 |

For PuLP documentation, visit https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/