# clicking on ">" (next) button returns silent error

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

I would like to scrape all the statistics in the page
https://fantasy.premierleague.com/statistics

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import numpy as np

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

import time
start = time.process_time()

time.sleep(3)
s = Service(path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=s)
#go to page
driver.get('https://fantasy.premierleague.com/statistics')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)

#accept cookies
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[5]/button[1]'))).click()
except:
    pass

list= np.arange(1, 22, 1).tolist()

for i in list:
    #extract table on the first page
    content = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")
    table = soup.find_all('table',attrs={'class':'Table-ziussd-1 ElementTable-sc-1v08od9-0 dUELIG OZmJL'})
    
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    df.drop(columns=df.columns[0], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df.to_parquet(f'table_pg_{i}_{date}.parquet.gzip')
    pd.read_parquet(f'table_pg_{i}_{date}.parquet.gzip')

    #scroll down to get the page data below the first scroll
    scrollDown = "window.scrollBy(0,2000);"
    driver.execute_script(scrollDown)
    #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(50, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    try:
        #click on the next button
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/button[3]/svg'))).click()
    except:
        pass
        
print('Execution Time: ', time.process_time() - start)

#check the last table
pd.read_parquet(f'table_pg_{i}_{date}.parquet.gzip')
```

The code does not return any error message, but the last table scraped should be on page 21,
as in the screenshot below
[image]

whereas my parquet file returns the results on the first page.

[image]

Both the previous and next buttons have the same CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this command try changing from `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/button[3]/svg'))).click()` to

```py
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button svg[class*='ChevronRight']"))).click()
```

Also make sure you are scrolling to the bottom so this element becomes clickable

Comment: changed it to CSS_SELECTOR and it worked up until the second page, but not to the 21st page. It seems that it is regarding the scrolling issue.

I commented out the ScrollDown execution, as the next button is visible without it. 
What happens then is the parquet file contains page 1, page 2, page 1, page 2, page 1, page 2, up until the 21st iteration. 
That is what also visible with the naked eye, the page goes back and forth between page 1 and 2..

Comment: both the previous and next buttons have the same CSS Selectors

Comment: but the svg classes are different.

Comment: I see, you are right. See the updated answer

Comment: I remember scraping that website to get some data to respond to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73180343/how-to-create-a-list-of-n-items-with-a-budget-constraint-and-multiple-conditions After responding, I realized I didn't need selenium for it. What can you do...

Answer (score 1):

You surely must have a reason to use selenium.. but just in case, here is a less overhead..ish solution, avoiding Selenium:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/'

r = requests.get(url)
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['elements'])
df.sort_values(by=['total_points'], inplace=True,  ascending=False)
print(df[['web_name', 'now_cost', 'form', 'total_points']])
```

Result:

```
web_name    now_cost    form    total_points
393 Haaland 119 11.2    67
91  Toney   71  7.5 45
538 Kane    114 6.7 40
259 Mitrović    68  6.5 39
314 Rodrigo 64  6.3 38
... ... ... ... ...
243 Garner  45  0.0 0
0   Cédric  42  0.0 0
86  Senesi  45  -0.2    -1
412 Shaw    47  -0.2    -1
410 Maguire 47  -0.2    -1
624 rows × 4 columns
```

Data in that webpage is being pulled dynamically from an API endpoint. This is visible in Dev tools - Network tab. By scraping that endpoint, you get a fairly large JSON object, which you can dissect and extract the visible table in page, and also other stuffs, if you are so inclined (just inspect it).

This is python Requests documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/